# Can I purchase the SC2 franchise (or any Blizzard game for the matter) from the US Battle.net store even though I live in Europe?

Tags: battle.net

Since the franchise is on sale right now (and because I want to maximize my "bang to buck" ratio), I'm considering buying the franchise from the US store and gifting it to my EU account instead of buying it straight from the EU store.

Is such a thing possible and, if so, does it violate Blizzard's terms of service?

In addition, will there be any gameplay perks due to e.g. regional restrictions? I've read about [Global play](https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/global-play), but I'd rather make sure that no subtle issues pop up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can!

As seen in [this post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/1y3myg/can_i_purchase_a_copy_of_ros_from_the_us_blizzard/), a guy asked if it's possible to buy *Diablo III: Reaper of Souls* in US store and gift it to his EU account. After a while he got the following response from [Blizzard](http://blizzard.com):

> ...
>
> If your brother will buy the legal copy of the game and he will gift you the valid code, you can upgrade your Diablo III account to ROS without any troubles and you will be able to play with your friend on European region of the game naturally.
>
> ...

Full text can be found in the link to the post

Comment: Although implied by the OP, it is not mentioned, however, whether or not he used e.g. a US-issued credit/debit/etc card or a card that was issued in a European country.

Comment: Actually scratch my last comment, looks like such a thing is possible: http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/20t75k/eu_customers_can_get_standard_ros_for_2480_how_to/

Comment: Yes thanks to Battle.net app you can change where your region is.

Comment: I can now confirm that it is indeed possible to gift both WoL and HotS from the US store to yourself and activate both of them on your account.

Also, you may need to log out of Battle.net and log in again in order to make the app/website display that the game keys have been activated.